# Is there a way to know if the windows screen display is updated/changed

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

We have a requirement to check any customer is using the application. On the client system our application will run in full screen mode. Based on the user activity the display will be updated.But the problem is I dont have any access to the source code of the application. So I am thinking if I can get any general events from windows when the screen is updated. If the screen is updating then I can consider that some customer is using the application

I am thinking of other approach is to get the screenshots in different intervals and compare. If both the images are matched then assuming it to be in idle mode or else some user activity is going on. If Ican get display update events then that will be easy for to handle.

Please let me know if you have any other approaches

Comment: Maybe you can write a separate app that runs when the user is using the application. Your new app could be used to detect mouse movement or mouse clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. But our application will not use normal mouse or keyboard .. We are using our own device which will take the customer inputs

Comment: Ok, then the application I am suggesting could listen for customer input events.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get those events to new application. The customer input events(messages) will be posted to the application window only. Is there a way I can check what messages are posted to  other application windows ?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't have enough information about your environment to be much help.

Comment: What is the definition of "using the application"?

Comment: Like in the Net banking, if the user doesnt use the banking page for specific time then it will logout the page.  Like the sameway for our application if user is not inputting any value from the input device then we need to report that user session has timed out.

Comment: A banking application resets the inactivity timer, whenever the browser submits an HTTP request. This is *very* different from what you are trying to accomplish, which amounts to a combination of `SetTimer` and `GetLastInputInfo`. Without knowing the *specific* problem you are trying to solve, this question isn't answerable. Please read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).